# azure monitor to alert on low space on /root , /var and /etc

Tags: azure, azure-monitor, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have Azure Linux VMs for which i want to configure Azure-Monitor Alerts when my /root,/etc and /var volumes are more than 90% utilized. Please suggest way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a KQL to achieve this.

For example,

```
InsightsMetrics
| where Computer in (
"CH1-UBNTVM", //Linux
"DC10.na.contosohotels.com" // Windows
)
| where Namespace == "LogicalDisk"
| where Name == "FreeSpacePercentage"
| extend Disk=tostring(todynamic(Tags)["vm.azm.ms/mountId"])
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Disk, Computer
| project TimeGenerated, Disk, Computer, Val
| where Val > 90
```

[image]

More info can be found here :- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/831491/how-to-setup-azure-alert-when-disk-space-is-90-for.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to enlarge the disk space of your Azure VM?

I do know you want to enlarge your VM partition.

All the code, please log in your virtual machine, input in terminal, thanks!

Just use the code `df -iTh`to check your VM disk space, output just like below:

```
Filesystem     Type     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs   117K   378  116K    1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs      123K   721  122K    1% /run
/dev/sda1      ext4       2.3M  297K  2.0M   13% /
tmpfs          tmpfs      123K     1  123K    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          tmpfs      123K     4  123K    1% /run/lock
tmpfs          tmpfs       25K   120   25K    1% /run/user/1000
```

Which partitions mounted at your `/root`, `/etc` and `/var`?

You can find the result from the display of `df -hTi`.

Enlarge or extend or resize your Azure VM follow below:

First, you need to know which partition mounted at your less disk target direction, e.g: `/root`;

Second, you need to enlarge or extend or resize that target partition;

Third, expand your disks on Azure Linux VM, please refer:

[Expand virtual hard disks on a Linux VM with the Azure CLI(Azure Linux VM Document)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/expand-disks)

OVER!